# О глаголе "миновать"

Tags: лексика

Как будет правильно: "минует 10 лет" или "минуют 10 лет"?

Answer (score 2):

Минует, единственное число.

Но проблема не в глаголе "миновать", а в присутствии слова "лет".

У [Розенталя об этом](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm):

> Форма единственного числа сказуемого употребляется при обозначении
>   меры веса, пространства, времени и т. д., так как в этом случае
>   имеется в виду единое целое, например: *На покраску крыши ушло
>   двадцать килограммов олифы; До конца пути оставалось пятнадцать
>   километров; На выполнение всей работы понадобится шесть месяцев.*
>
> **Сказуемые-глаголы** (обычно со значением протекания времени)
>   **ставятся в единственном числе, если в составе количественно-именного сочетания** (обычно оборота) **имеются слова лет, месяцев, дней,
>   часов** и т. д., например: *Прошло сто лет* (Пушкин); *Однако уже,
>   кажется, одиннадцать часов пробило* (Тургенев); *Вот два года моей
>   жизни вычеркнуто* (Горький).
>
> Но при другом лексическом значении глагола возможна форма
>   множественного числа сказуемого, например: Десять секунд показались
>   мне за целый час (Л. Толстой).